# Jest-Puppeteer test with React doesn't type text in input

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I have an app created from "create-react-app", and i've added puppeteer for running end-to-end tests.
While trying to run a test for logging in, I am not able to type text in the log in form inputs.

jest-puppeteer.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  server: {
    command: `npm start`,
    port: 3000,
    launchTimeout: 10000,
    debug: true
  }
};
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
  testRegex: './*\\index.test\\.js$'
};
```

my login test:

```
it('should login test user', async () => {
    await page.waitForSelector('form[name="login"]');
    await expect(page).toFillForm('form[name="login"]', {
      username: 'abcd',
      password: 'abcd'
    });
    await expect(page).toMatchElement('input[name="username"]', { text: 'abcd' });
  }
```

I also tried using any of the following:

`await page.type('#username', 'abcd');`

```
await page.click('input[name="username"]');
await page.type('input[name="username"]', 'abcd');
```

`await expect(page).toFill('input[name="username"]', 'abcd');`

But still, it doesn't type any text. I wonder if my setup is suitable for create-react-app. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what happens exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer is running headless by default, I believe it does run but in the background.

Add the following lines to your jest-puppeteer.config.js:

```
launch: {
    headless: false,
}
```

so it will look like that:

```
module.exports = {
  launch: {
        headless: false,
  },
  server: {
    command: `npm start`,
    port: 3000,
    launchTimeout: 10000,
    debug: true
  }
};
```

This will actually open the browser and you'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Oh my, it ran the app and I thought it was the test app. Thanks! The bounty is still locked, i'll award you once it opens

Answer (score 1):

Before going on, please check your app and check if the selectors are wrong or something. Somehow i prefer to use only puppeteer alone before using test framework like Jest or anything you like and see if the code running well and smoothly.

And don't forget to add `headless : false` for the beginning test.

You can try this one.

```
describe('Login', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await page.goto('https://localhost:3000');
    })

    it('should login test user', async () => {

        const waitForTheName = await page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');
        const focusInputName = await page.focus('input[name="username"]')
        const writeInputName = await page.keyboard.type('abcd')

        const focusInputPaswd = await page.focus('input[name="password"]')
        const writeInputPaswd = await page.keyboard.type('abcd')

        await expect(page).toFillForm('form[name="login"]', {
            username: 'abcd',
            password: 'abcd'
        })

        await expect(page).toMatchElement('input[name="username"]', { text: 'abcd' })
    }
})
```